# Getting "TokenError: Invalid "code" in request" error

Tags: javascript, backend

I have: "TokenError: Invalid "code" in request" error. I don't know where it is. But I tested it and code that makes this error is:

```
const passport = require("passport");
const DiscordStrategy = require("passport-discord");
const User = require('../database/schemas/User');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.discordId)
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (discordId, done) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ discordId });
        return user ? done(null, user): done(null, null)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        done(err, null);
    }
});

passport.use(
    new DiscordStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.DASHBOARD_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.DASHBOARD_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.DASHBOARD_CALLBACK_URL,
    scope: ['identify', 'guilds'],
    }, async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        const { id, username, discriminator, avatar, guilds } = profile;
        console.log(id, username, discriminator, avatar, guilds);
        try {
            const findUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
                { discordId: id },
                {
                discordTag: `${username}#${discriminator}`,
                avatar,
                guilds,  
                },
             { new: true }
            );
            if (findUser) {
                console.log('User was found');
                return done(null, findUser);
            } else {
                const newUser = await User.create({
                    discordId: id,
                    discordTag: `${username}#${discriminator}`,
                    avatar,
                    guilds,
                });
                return done(null, newUser);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return done(err, null);
        }
    })
);
```

I tried everything but nothing helps. I'm using:

`"dotenv": "^8.2.0", "express": "^4.17.1", "mongoose": "^5.12.4", "nodemon": "^2.0.7", "passport": "^0.4.1", "passport-discord": "^0.1.4", "react": "^17.0.2"`

This is error:

```
TokenError: Invalid "code" in request.
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (C:\Users\MeenQ\OneDrive\Pulpit\Pulpit\dev\VSC\work\discordbot-v12\DiscordBot-v12\djs-backend\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:358:12) 
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (C:\Users\MeenQ\OneDrive\Pulpit\Pulpit\dev\VSC\work\discordbot-v12\DiscordBot-v12\djs-backend\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:405:16)  
    at C:\Users\MeenQ\OneDrive\Pulpit\Pulpit\dev\VSC\work\discordbot-v12\DiscordBot-v12\djs-backend\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:175:45
    at C:\Users\MeenQ\OneDrive\Pulpit\Pulpit\dev\VSC\work\discordbot-v12\DiscordBot-v12\djs-backend\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:191:18
    at passBackControl (C:\Users\MeenQ\OneDrive\Pulpit\Pulpit\dev\VSC\work\discordbot-v12\DiscordBot-v12\djs-backend\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MeenQ\OneDrive\Pulpit\Pulpit\dev\VSC\work\discordbot-v12\DiscordBot-v12\djs-backend\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the error tell you which line it was on? Please put the full text of the error in your question.

Comment: Added Full Error at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

for my token error, the client secret was wrong.. make sure & dbl check all your variables..